# swift overload operator for member type

Tags: ios, swift, overloading

I have a question about operator overloading in swift.
In my code I have a structure that goes like this:

```
struct Position {

///The horisontal index for a chessboard [A-H]
let horisontal : String

///The vertical index for a chessboard [1-8]
let vertical : Int
}
```

What I need next is a way to change the horizontal index in the manner of index +- some integer number. What I do then is to overload the '+' operator, like this:

```
func + (left: Position.horisontal, right: Int) -> Bool {
      //Some implementation in here
}
```

And then my world crashes. The compiler tells me: "'horisontal is not a member type of 'Position'"
What is it that I do not know to help me in this situation? Why the compiler refuses to acknowledge the existence of 'horisontal'? What else can I do to achieve addition between a String and an Int?

**Remark**
Mind you, this works just fine, but I do not think it is in the good spirit of operator overloading:

```
func + (left: String, right: Int) -> Bool {
      //Some implementation in here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why the compiler refuses to acknowledge the existence of 'horisontal'?

Because `horisontal` [sic] is not a type, it's a member of the `Position` type.

A more appropriate solution would be to define a closed `enum` for row and column positions.

Comment: No, I mean closed as in _closed interval_.

Comment: I see what you mean now, and it is very cool solution, but I was aiming at syntax like, for instance if we have position _A1_: `piece.position.horisontal + 1` to be equal to _B2_ in the end.

Comment: These two things are not incompatible. That said, I don't think it's semantically appropriate to be able to increment or decrement row or column individually like that. In chess, it's really more about moving a piece from its start position to any other valid position.

Comment: Well, to define a valid position, you have to analyse it first. And you always start at your current position and end at the edge of the board (if appropriate by piece type). So, you have to know all the possible positions along the way which means, well, iterating through all the possible tiles as type permits and iterating means +- 1 (Oh, and I meant _B1_ in my previous comment).

Comment: What I'm objecting to is the semantics of a top-level operator for manipulating positions like that. Of course you add/subtract row and column to calculate possible positions.